# Unpivot the dataframe Pyspark with dynamic columns

Tags: pyspark

I have data like this

[image]

I want to unpivot the dataframe by calling the columns dynamically without hardcoding.
How do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `array` of struct column that combines the columns and column values using list comprehension. Explode the `struct` column using `inline`.

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([
('78','20','19','90'),
 ('78','20','19','&')
],
('Machines',  'Books',  'Vehicles', 'Plants'))

df.show()

df.withColumn('tab', F.array(*[F.struct(lit(x).alias('Fields'), col(x).alias('Count')).alias(x) for x in df.columns])).selectExpr('inline(tab)').show()


+---+------+------+
| Id|  Date|Amount|
+---+------+------+
|  1|202201|    50|
|  1|202202|   150|
|  1|202203|   100|
|  2|202201|    10|
|  2|202202|      |
|  2|202203|    50|
|  3|202201|    20|
|  3|202202|    10|
|  3|202203|      |
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Very clever solutiun @wwnde. It worked very nice. But I can't understand why there isn't a `transpose` function that would do this job. In most of the time you would not know the column names so one would need a dynamic transposing. Perhaps I missing the `R` language in which a simple `t(df)` would to the trick lol.